# Passing an array or a variable number of parameters to format function in scala

Tags: scala

In Scala we can use the `format` method on a string and use format specifiers like example

```
"The %s costs %s".format(name, price.toString)
```

I need to define a method that takes a variable number of string parameters.  Is there a way i can pass an array, list or a variable number of parameters to format ?.

Comment: Well `format` already receives a variable number of parameters, so you can just do this: `def test(args: String*): String = "The %s costs %s".format(args)` or if you prefer to receives a collection then you can do this: `def test(args: List[String]): String = "The %s costs %s".format(args : _*)`. - Just remember that if you pass more arguments than the ones required those will be ignored.